# Wrap interactive shell in python while allowing for command-line completion

Tags: python, shell

I have a long-running interactive shell with command-line completion that I would like to wrap in python. The goal is to replace a bash wrapper with a python one, to benefit from standard library modules like `argparse`. The python process would be one or more un-packaged script (so preferably no 3rd party libraries).

The shell is to interact with a server, but we can assume that I want to start a bash session and be able to send commands and see output, and that I want to be able to use bash completion.

Comment: check out "sh".